# Javascript Question regarding appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Im just learning javascript and I'm just wondering why this doesn't work. I've created a button and when it is clicked I assigned a function which is supposed to append some text to all my paragraphs. I don't know why it doesn't work:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>javascript test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function appendStuff(){
 var node = document.getElementsByTagName("P");
 node.appendChild.createTextNode('Here's some text');

 return true;
 }

</script>
<noscript>
Your browser doesn't support javascript.
</noscript>

<input type="submit" value="click me" onclick="appendStuff();" />

<p>
This is the first paragraph.
</p>

<p>
This is the second paragraph.
</p>

<p>
This is the third paragraph.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should pass new node as argument to appendChild method, like here:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("P");
for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
   nodes[i].appendChild(document.createTextNode("Here's some text"));
}
```

Comment: use like this "Here\'s some text" inside createTextNode function

Comment: Can you explain exactly what this line is doing:    for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++)

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns array. Using for loop I iterate through all paragraph nodes and append "Here's some text" to each of them.

Comment: what does nodes.length do exactly?

Comment: nodes is array. it has property length which contains number of elements in array. nodes.length returns number of paragraph elements, returned by getElementsByTagName method.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByTagName returns a list (array) of element instead of just one, you have to pick up the one you'd like to append (i.e. node[0])

Comment: *getElementsByTagName* returns a live *NodeList*, which is a collection of DOM elements. It is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
function function11() {
   var myNode = document.createTextNode("New Text Node");
   document.body.appendChild(myNode);
}
</script>
<button onclick="function11();">Create text node</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function appendStuff(){
     var node = document.getElementsByTagName("P");
     var txt = 'Here is some text';
     var newT = document.createTextNode(txt);
    node.appendChild(newT);
     return true;
     }
```

Try the above method!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
> <script language="javascript"
> type="text/javascript">
```

The language attribute has been deprecated for over a decade, it should not be used.

```
> function appendStuff(){   var node = document.getElementsByTagName("P");  
>   node.appendChild.createTextNode('Here's some text');
>   return true;
> }
```

As others have pointed out, *getElemetsByTagName* returns a live [*NodeList*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177), which has a length property and whose members can be accessed by index. Note that while it is array-like, it is not an array.

A text element can be appended to the first node in the NodeList using:

```
  node[0].appendChild(document.createTextNode("Here's some text"));
```

However it is much safer to first see if `node[0]` exists before attempting to call one of its methods.

```
> <noscript> Your browser doesn't
> support javascript. </noscript>
```

The fact that a browser displays a [noscript](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#edef-NOSCRIPT) element doesn't necessarily mean that the browser doesn't support javascript. The description of a noscript element includes:

```
The NOSCRIPT element allows authors to provide 
alternate content when a script is not executed.
```

[W3C, *HTML4.01*, §18.3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#edef-NOSCRIPT)

```
> <input type="submit" value="click me"
> onclick="appendStuff();" />
```

An input with a type of submit is intended to be in a form and be used to submit the form. A more appropriate value for the type attribute here is "button". And the XML-style closing tag is unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

document.getElementsByTagName return 'array' of fetched doms rather than one dom. so you need to specify single dom with for loop of this array or sth likely.

Comment: *getElementsByTagName* returns a live *NodeList*, which is a collection of DOM elements. It is not an array.